# How to delete certain line from file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a text file with line containing only comma. How can I delete this particular line? Consider following example:

```
CREATE TABLE ENTERPRISE.TSDAILYACCTSUMMARY (
    TSDAILYACCTID FOR COLUMN TSDAYID    INTEGER INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    ,
    TIMESHEETDATE FOR COLUMN TSDATE     DATE DEFAULT NULL ,
```

How to delete third line?

Answer (score 4):

try

```
 awk '$1 == "," && NF==1 { next ; } { print ; } ' file > other_file
```

or

```
 grep  -v '^[ ]*,[ ]*$' file > other_file
```

or

```
 sed -i -e '/^[ \t]*,[ \t]*$/d' original_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i -ne 'print if ! /^\s*,\s*$/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

A more terse `awk` solution can be:

```
awk '!(NF==1&&$1==",")' /path/to/file
```

- `awk` defaults to printing the entire line as long as the predicate/filter/condition is `true`.
- In this case, the condition is ***not*** a single field (`NF==1`) *being* `","`.
- Therefore, only line 3 *will **not*** match the condition, and the other lines are printed out.